# amp-list component error in amp for email

Tags: email, amp-html, amp-list, amp-email

I am new to AMP for Email and I am trying it out now! I am using the amp-list component in my email body to fetch the remote server json content. But I am getting the below js error when i checked in my browser console. Also in my Gmail inbox in the mail I received its blank.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Class$obf_1013: [https://dynamicmail-pa.googleapis.com/v2/xhrs:proxy?alt=protojson] ti: Unsupported HTTP status: 400: Class$obf_1011: [object Object]

template-impl.js:241 Error proxying amp-list templates: Request viewerRenderTemplate failed: Error: Class$obf_1013: [https://dynamicmail-pa.googleapis.com/v2/xhrs:proxy?alt=protojson] ti: Unsupported HTTP status: 400: Class$obf_1011: [object Object]​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the correct headers to send for AMP to work in gmail:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail/security-requirements?hl=ur#gmail

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://mail.google.com
AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: <your sender email address>
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin
```

Answer (score -1):

We need to set the Content-Type & Access Control headers for CORS request like -

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```